# What's the story behind the name of the SOS (Son of Strike) debugger extension?

Tags: .net, debugging, sos

What's the significance of the name "Son of Strike"? Does it serve any meaning or does it just sound cool?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Jason Zander's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2003/10/21/53581.aspx) explains it perfectly:

> The original name of the CLR team
>   (chosen by team founder and former
>   Microsoft Distinguished Engineer Mike
>   Toutonghi) was "Lighting".  Larry
>   Sullivan's dev team created an ntsd
>   extension dll to help facilitate the
>   bootstrapping of v1.0.  We called it
>   strike.dll (get it?  "Lightning
>   Strike"?  yeah, I know, ba'dump bum). 
>   PSS really needed this in order to
>   give us information back to the team
>   when it was time to debug nasty stress
>   failures, which are almost always done
>   with the Windows debugger stack.  But
>   we didn't want to hand out our full
>   strike.dll, because it contained some
>   "dangerous" commands that if you
>   really didn't have our source code
>   could cause you confusion and pain
>   (even to other Microsoft teams).  So I
>   pushed the team to create "Son of
>   Strike" (Simon from our dev takes
>   credit/blame for this), and we shipped
>   it with the product starting with
>   Everett (aka V1.1).

Also, I had heard of the CLR being referred to as "COM+ 2.0" before, but apparently it's had a few names in its time (from [here](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=DM_CLR)):

> The CLR runtime lives in a DLL called MSCOREE.DLL, which stands for Microsoft Common Object Runtime Execution Engine. "**Common Object Runtime**," or COR, is one of the many names this technology has had during its lifetime. Others include **Next Generation Windows Services (NGWS)**, the **Universal Runtime (URT)**, **Lightning**, **COM+**, and **COM+ 2.0**

Comment: Insightful history. I always used to wonder about SOS.dll extension's abbreviation and what could it really mean. and In fact I always used to speculate MSCOREE.dll as Microsoft CORe Execution Engine. Thanks @chris for saving me from an embarrassment.

Answer (score 5):

This was discussed in a Scott Hanselman podcast with Tess Ferrandez a while back. It derives from an internal codename used early in the .NET platform. More info in the [show transcript](http://perseus.franklins.net/hanselminutes_0186.pdf).

Comment: Can you provide a summary? If nothing else, because of link rot (which has already happened in this case).

Comment: Apparently the codename for the CLR was "Lightning" and so the debugging extension was named "Strike", then "Son of Strike" arose somehow from that as a descendant.

Answer (score 1):

**Mario Hewardt** of Microsoft explained with details:

> When Microsoft was originally developing .NET 1.0, they had the need
> for an extension similar to SOS so that they can debug failures within
> the CLR itself and they used an extension that they developed called
> Strike. The usefulness of Strike was very apparent, and as Microsoft
> support engineers would use that extension to figure out customer's
> problems, customers wanted to get their hands on this particular
> extension.
>
> Unfortunately, Strike exposed a little too much information
> about the internals of the CLR, so they ended up creating a slightly
> trimmed down version of it known as SOS, and that's what's publicly
> available in your .NET framework installation.

[image: .NET sos extension for Windbg]

Really cool.