# What does the acronym EE mean in the .NET reference source?

Tags: c#, .net

In the .NET reference source for the `String` class, there are various comments referencing something called the `EE`.

[The first is on `m_stringLength`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#54):

> ```
> //NOTE NOTE NOTE NOTE
> //These fields map directly onto the fields in an EE StringObject.  See object.h for the layout.
> //
> [NonSerialized]private int  m_stringLength;
> ```

[It's found again again for `.Empty`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#72):

> ```
> // The Empty constant holds the empty string value. It is initialized by the EE during startup.
> // It is treated as intrinsic by the JIT as so the static constructor would never run.
> // Leaving it uninitialized would confuse debuggers.
> //
> //We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark this as a literal.
> //Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field which we can access 
> //from native.
> public static readonly String Empty;
> ```

It's also on [`Length`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#924):

> ```
> // Gets the length of this string
> //
> /// This is a EE implemented function so that the JIT can recognise is specially
> /// and eliminate checks on character fetchs in a loop like:
> ///        for(int I = 0; I < str.Length; i++) str[i]
> /// The actually code generated for this will be one instruction and will be inlined.
> ```

I would venture that it might have something to do with an **E**ngine or is **E**xternal, but I'd like an actual reference defining what it is.

What does the `EE` mean?

Comment: "execution engine", usually.

Comment: *Execution Engine*  as in MSCOR **EE** .dll

Comment: Ha, I would have figured it was `MSCoreE`.  Shouldn't they have labeled it `MSCoreEE.dll`.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess `MSCOREE` stands for [Microsoft Common Object Runtime Execution Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3573049/548304)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`EE` is an acronym for the `Execution Engine`.

The `Microsoft Core Execution Engine` (as found in `mscoree.dll`) is the bootstrapper that every .NET program calls to load the CLR and execute the IL code. It's an unmanaged piece of code.