# How do i step in to the variable code not only definition?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

Right click on the variable i can make go to definition.

```
superMarquee1.StartMarquee();
```

I make right mouse button then go to definition on StartMarquee then it jump to a class with this:

```
public void StartMarquee();
```

But what i want is to get to the area/place where the StartMarquee is in use where it make the start not the variable definition. If i make F11 or F10 on a breakpoint it will continue the program will not lead me to where its using this method.

This superMarquee is a dll UserControl i added through the toolbox > choose items and added the dll then dragged the usercontrol to my form1 designer.
I also added this dll to my project as reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging a third-party DLL in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349918/debugging-a-third-party-dll-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the source of a dll if you don't have the source code. A dll file is a compiled file, which means it doesn't contain the original source by itself; you need to have the source code from some other source if you want to see how it is implemented.

If you want to understand why the method does something, online documentation is probably your best option. If there isn't any, you can look into the dll's compiled Intermediate Language with a tool like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).